# Positioning AJAX results in the right DIV by using "rel" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="ct-slide" style="left: 55px;">
    <div class="ct-menu-text shadow" style="display: block;">
        <ul>
                <li rel="electronica" data-id="1" title="Electrónica">Electrónica <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
                <li rel="hogar" data-id="3" title="Hogar">Hogar <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
                <li rel="ropa-zapatos-y-accesorios" data-id="4" title="Ropa, Zapatos y Accesorios">Ropa, Zapatos y Accesorios <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
                <li rel="joyas-y-relojes" data-id="5" title="Joyas y Relojes">Joyas y Relojes <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
                <li rel="salud-y-cuidado-personal" data-id="6" title="Salud y Cuidado Personal">Salud y Cuidado Personal <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
                <li rel="deportes-y-actividades-outdoors" data-id="7" title="Deportes y Actividades Outdoors">Deportes y Actividades Outdoors <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
                <li rel="libros" data-id="8" title="Libros">Libros <div class="ct-pointer-cover"></div><div class="ct-pointer"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div rel="electronica" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div rel="hogar" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div rel="ropa-zapatos-y-accesorios" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div rel="joyas-y-relojes" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div rel="salud-y-cuidado-personal" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div rel="deportes-y-actividades-outdoors" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div rel="libros" class="ct-submenu shadow" style="width: 1665px; display: none;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div title="Click para abrir" class="ct-open" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div style="" title="Click para cerrar" class="ct-close"></div>
</div>
```

As yours can see each LI and DIV has the same `rel` attribute, I need to write the returned HTML by this AJAX call in the proper DIV element but I can't get it to work. Of example if I move over `li rel="electronica"` the content returned by the AJAX call (see code below) should be displayed in `div rel="electronica"`, how? any help?

```
// begin: categories picker
var k = 1;
$(".ct-menu, .ct-menu-text").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var next = $(this).closest("div[id]").nextAll().length;

    $("#selected_category").attr("value", id);

    if (next > 0) {
        k = k - next;
        $(this).closest("div[id]").nextAll().remove();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length != 0) {
                $(".ct-submenu").attr('rel').eq(id).append('<div class="product-left" id="cstep' + (k + 1) + '"><ul id="step' + (k + 1) + '"></ul></div>');
                var LIs = "";
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $.each(value, function(i, v) {
                        LIs += '<li><a class="step ct-sub-menu-text" data-id="' + i + '" href="#">' + v + '</a></li>';
                    })
                });
                $('#step' + (k + 1)).html(LIs);
                k++;
            }
        }
    });
});
// end: categories picker
```

Comment: The `rel` attribute describes the nature of a relationship, it isn't there for you to use for abritary data. Use `data-*` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the clicked `LI`'s `rel` in a variable. Then use that variable in a selector to find the matching `DIV`.

When you tried `$(".ct-submenu").attr("rel").eq(0)`, that doesn't work because `.attr("rel")` is not a selector, it's a method that returns the contents of the `rel` attribute.

```
var k = 1;
$(".ct-menu, .ct-menu-text").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var next = $(this).closest("div[id]").nextAll().length;

    $("#selected_category").attr("value", id);

    if (next > 0) {
        k = k - next;
        $(this).closest("div[id]").nextAll().remove();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length != 0) {
                $(".ct-submenu[rel="+rel+"]").append('<div class="product-left" id="cstep' + (k + 1) + '"><ul id="step' + (k + 1) + '"></ul></div>');
                var LIs = "";
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $.each(value, function(i, v) {
                        LIs += '<li><a class="step ct-sub-menu-text" data-id="' + i + '" href="#">' + v + '</a></li>';
                    })
                });
                $('#step' + (k + 1)).html(LIs);
                k++;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As Quentin commented, this isn't really appropriate use of the `rel` attribute. I suggest you give the `.ct-submenu` elements IDs, and put the matching ID in the LI's `data-submenu` attribute. Then you can do:

```
var rel = $(this).data('submenu');
```

and the selector in the callback would be:

```
$("#"+rel)
```

Comment: Fine, I did as you suggested and it works, just I don't know why when I move the mouse into the newly created LI the same function isn't triggered, can you take a look and try to find why it doesn't work? I see over and over and without success

Comment: The new LIs are put in `#step`, I don't see a binding for this. I don't even see it in the HTML.